# iOS Casting to a BOOL

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting

Are these two lines of code different or the same (Edit: Do they do the same thing, typecast to a boolean?):

```
BOOL isRegistered = (BOOL)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"DEVICE_REGISTERED"];

BOOL isRegistered = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Is Registered"] boolValue];
```

In iOS8.1 the first one is definitely failing. The cast to a bool is not working, the cast is always returning as false. The value is being stored (for the second example) like so:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", registerSuccess] 
                                          forKey:@"Is Registered"];
```

registerSuccess is a value returned from a web service (JSON).

Comment: You can also consider using NSUserDefaults setBool:forKey: and boolForKey: methods and make sure the value you originally save is a bool value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, consider using `NSUserDefaults boolForKey:`.

Answering your question:

```
BOOL isRegistered = (BOOL)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"DEVICE_REGISTERED"];
```

Here NSUserDefaults return `NSNumber`, and you are trying to cast pointer to NSNumber into BOOL. If your settings is not defined at all, `valueForKey` will return nil, it will be considered false. If any value is set for this settings, `valueForKey` will return pointer to NSNumber and when you will try to convert it to BOOL, your will get always True.

```
BOOL isRegistered = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"isRegistered"] boolValue];
```

Here NSUserDefaults return `NSNumber` to you and you call `boolValue` on it, and it's working as you are expecting. If settings is not defined at all, `valueForKey` will return `nil`, calling `boolValue` on nil will return another nil, which is cast to false;

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. This was what I was looking for, an explanation of the difference between the two. The first one is legacy code which I didn't write, the second one is mine. I am going to rewrite using boolForKey and storing an NSNumber as bool.

Answer (score 6):

You cast a NSString object to a bool, that will never do anything useful. A cast does not change or convert something, it just silences the compiler.

Assuming that `isRegistered` is a NSNumber object, as it would be deserialised as such from the JSON response:
Use a NSNumber

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:registerSuccess forKey:@"isRegistered"];
```

and

```
BOOL isRegistered = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"isRegistered"] boolValue];
```

or a Bool directly

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:[registerSuccess boolValue]forKey:@"isRegistered"];

BOOL isRegistered = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isRegistered];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest saving the value as follows:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:registerSuccess] forKey:@"DEVICE_REGISTERED"];
```

Then read the value back as you do in the second line of the code you show, but with the key @"DEVICE_REGISTERED".

Answer (score 1):

I use below code to write and read a boolean value

```
// assume that "isDeviceRegisterred" is a boolean data type parameter that comes from the web service
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:isDeviceRegisterred  forKey:@"DEVICE_REGISTERED"];

BOOL isRegistered = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"DEVICE_REGISTERED"];
```

Comment: so no matter what, this device will be registered

Comment: I just focused on the main problem, but to notify the beginners I changed it dynamic.

Comment: the main problem is the misunderstanding of what casting does.